# Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found

Tags: php, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am generating the PDF file but facing the trouble. Can anybody tell me the solution of this error. Below is the code that I used for that. I include the tcpdf for this but there is a fatal error that saying that tcpdf file in not available or we can say not found.

```
<?php
    $tcpdf_include_dirs = array(realpath('tcpdf.php'), '/usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf.php', '/usr/share/tcpdf/tcpdf.php', '/usr/share/php-tcpdf/tcpdf.php', '/var/www/tcpdf/tcpdf.php', '/var/www/html/tcpdf/tcpdf.php', '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
    foreach ($tcpdf_include_dirs as $tcpdf_include_path) {
        if (@file_exists($tcpdf_include_path)) {
            require_once($tcpdf_include_path);
            break;
        }
    }

    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); // Create New PDF Doc
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR); //Setup a document information

    include("db_connection.php");       

    $isql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `cpdf`") OR die("Data Select problem: ".mysqli_error($con));
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($isql);

    $pdf->AddPage(); //Add new page

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($isql)){
        $firstname = $row['fname'];
        $lastname = $row['lname'];
        $fullname = $firstname ." ".$lastname;
        ?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PDF Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <div>
                <div><img style="width: 100%; height: 20%" src="image/FlZJRBAXRlweb design.idevtechnolabs.socialsigna.l.JPG"/></div>
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 30%">
                    <table style="float: right; border: 2;">
                        <tr style="width: 10%;"><td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $fullname; ?></td></tr>
                        <tr style="width: 20%;"><td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $row['add1']; ?></td></tr>
                        <tr style="width: 20%;"><td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $row['add2']; ?></td></tr>
                        <tr style="width: 20%;"><td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $row['city']; ?></td></tr>
                        <tr style="width: 20%;"><td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $row['state']; ?></td></tr>
                        <tr style="width: 20%;"><td style="text-align: left;"><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; height: 10%;">
                    <b>Subject:</b> <?php echo $row['subject']; ?>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 40%; width: 100%;">
                    <p style="text-align: justify;">Hey, <br /><br /> Mr. <?php echo $fullname; ?>. This is to inform you that a day after tomorrow is the last date of your invoice payment. This is a reminder notice to pay your <?php echo $row['bill']; ?> invoice amount our nearest store and takes advantage of our services.</p>
                    <p style="text-align: justify; text-indent: 4em;">We request you to pay your <?php echo $row['bill']; ?> Bill as soon as possible.</p>
                    <span style="float: right;">Thank you,<br /><img src="#"/></span>
                </div><?php $pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0); 
                } 
                $pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'I'); ?>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the class in your tcpdf.php actually called TCPDF? Also you may have relative path issues. Is that the only error that you get or do you get a stack trace?

Comment: Yeah, I am facing only this error.

Comment: Before `$pdf = new TCPDF(` you should use `if(!class_exists('TCPDF')){die('TCPDF could not be loaded. Abort!');}` and your Fatal Error will go away.

Answer (score 3):

As a first step, comment out the first seven lines of code and add one new line of code that includes tcpdf.php using the full path to the file. If that doesn't work then you should check the contents of the tcpdf.php file to make sure that it hasn't been corrupted somewhere along the way. That is, make sure it still contains the code that declares the TCPDF class.

If that works then comment out the hard-coded include statement, uncomment the seven lines that were commented out earlier and add an echo statement to print out the `$tcpdf_include_path` variable during each iteration of that loop. As long as one of those paths match the hard-coded path that presumably worked earlier, then your code should work fine.

Finally, and I highly doubt this is the case, but if you happened to have a case-sensitive file system and you happened to have the tcpdf.php file saved as TCPDF.PHP, for example, then that might contribute to the problem. I'm only mentioning that possibility for completeness to the answer, but it is highly unlikely, especially based on the information you provided, that this is the problem in your case.