# Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in another path

Tags: php, class, tcpdf

when we click on link we want to **download php page Data** in Pdf format.

So we downloaded TCPDF from official [git hub link](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF)

we copied extracted folder to path : "**/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6**"

when we run the example code in browser : http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/tcpdf/examples/example_011.php we can able to download pdf.

when we tried same code in another path : http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/example_011.php , we are getting error as "`Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found` in" in line : **class MYPDF extends TCPDF {**

i checked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637344/fatal-error-class-tcpdf-not-found) but that don't work for me.

also i checked [link2](https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf/issues/107) & installed TCPDF via composer as below image. but still that error is there.

[image]

**example_011.php**

```
require_once('tcpdf_config.php');

// extend TCPF with custom functions
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    // Load table data from file
    public function LoadData($file) {
        // Read file lines
        $lines = file($file);
        $data = array();
        foreach($lines as $line) {
            $data[] = explode(';', chop($line));
        }
        return $data;
    }

    // Colored table
    public function ColoredTable($header,$data) {
        // Colors, line width and bold font
        $this->SetFillColor(255, 0, 0);
        // Header
        $w = array(40, 35, 40, 45);
        $num_headers = count($header);
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_headers; ++$i) {
            $this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C', 1);
        }
        $this->Ln();
        // Color and font restoration
        $this->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('');
        // Data
        $fill = 0;
        foreach($data as $row) {
            $this->Cell($w[0], 6, $row[0], 'LR', 0, 'L', $fill);
            $fill=!$fill;
        }
        $this->Cell(array_sum($w), 0, '', 'T');
    }
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 011', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 12);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// column titles
$header = array('Country', 'Capital', 'Area (sq km)', 'Pop. (thousands)');

// data loading
$data = $pdf->LoadData('data/table_data_demo.txt');

// print colored table
$pdf->ColoredTable($header, $data);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_011.pdf', 'I');
```

**Edit**

**tcpdfconfig.php**

```
require_once('config/tcpdf_config_alt.php');

// Include the main TCPDF library (search the library on the following directories).
$tcpdf_include_dirs = array(
    realpath('../tcpdf.php'),
    '/usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
    '/usr/share/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
    '/usr/share/php-tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
    '/var/www/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
    '/var/www/html/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
    '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php'
);
foreach ($tcpdf_include_dirs as $tcpdf_include_path) {
    if (@file_exists($tcpdf_include_path)) {
        require_once($tcpdf_include_path);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Edit2**

its working only when i include files in sub folder of **/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/tcpdf/** folder example :

```
/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/tcpdf/example1
/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/tcpdf/example1
```

if i copy example folder contents to another path , let say :
**/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/** its not working at all.....

Comment: You write that you change the path of you code,have you the right path for TCPDF  at include?

Comment: @dimis283 i copied the `tcpdf_include.php` file under `/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6`

Comment: @dimis283 sorry, i copied `tcpdf_config.php` file to `/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6` as i got `tcpdf_config.php` file under `config` folder....

Comment: It seems to have and other files at git hub link,maybe to have all of them at one folder and "include" from there the tcpdf_include.php?

Comment: @dimis283 sorry , i did't got, right now i copied the folder `tcpdf` to this path : `/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6` , please tell for which path i need to copy ?

Comment: At git hub link the tcpdf_config.php is at config folder as I see,the error is that the code can not find this  tcpdf_config.php

Comment: @dimis283 we  have `tcpdf_config.php` file under this path : `/var/www/html/sbdev2/php/site6/tcpdf/config` , is i need to copy files somewhere else ?

Comment: Maybe to do things like https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/tree/master/examples ?they have require_once('tcpdf_include.php'); at one example that I see.try to copy things from these examples

Comment: I also see tcpdf.php file,where it is at your folders

Comment: @dimis283 when i tried this link : `https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/master/examples/example_011.php` code i also copied `tcpdf_config_alt.php` file from `https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/tree/master/examples/config` & placed in config folder & tried in [test5.php](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/test5.php)

but it giving error `Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found`

Comment: @dimis283 sorry, updated error : `Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found` for link : http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/php/site6/test5.php

Comment: the examples include tcpdf_include and there is the code bellow,so to set there the right path? $tcpdf_include_dirs = array(
 realpath('../tcpdf.php'),
 '/usr/share/php/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
 '/usr/share/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
 '/usr/share/php-tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
 '/var/www/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
 '/var/www/html/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
 '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php'
);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131335/discussion-between-abcd-and-dimis283).

Answer (score 10):

I also faced this problem and atlast got the solution. 
Everything is fine, let every file remain at its original path only, just you need to open tcpdf_include.php and include the file tcpdf.php, thats all!
**require_once(...INSTALED DIRECTORY...\tcpdf.php');**
It will work, all the best

Answer (score 5):

In the **example 001** changed this line:

```
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');
```

Into this:

```
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('**C:\wamp\www\pdf2\tcpdf\tcpdf.php**');
```

And it works for me on a `WAMP`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This can't work because this is for Windows and he is using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the configurations found in **tcpdf_include.php** file. Change the first one to reflect the full path to your tcpdf folder e.g.

```
$tcpdf_include_dirs = array(
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . 'tcpdf.php'),// True source file
        realpath('tcpdf.php'),// Relative from $PWD
        '/var/www/html/timetablemaster/ttm/php_libs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
        '/usr/share/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
        '/usr/share/php-tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
        '/var/www/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
        '/var/www/html/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
        '/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php'
);
```